# Shuffle 16 bit vectors SSE

Tags: sse, simd

I am working on `SSE` and a newbie here. I am trying to use `shuffle` instruction to shuffle a 16 bit vector like below:

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Output:

```
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

How do I achieve the desired target? I am confused about the constant being used here and I don't see any 16 bit `shuffle` instruction. `shuffle` instruction is only available for 8 bit and 32 bit.

Comment: _"I don't see any 16 bit shuffle instruction"_ There's `PSHUFHW`/`PSHUFLW`, but I don't think they can do what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You can always use a smaller-granularity shuffle.  If the shuffle control isn't a compile-time constant, it can be cumbersome to turn a vector of word indices into a vector of byte indices, though.  AVX512 fixes this by providing full cross-lane variable shuffles with byte, word, dword, and qword granularity.  (vpermb/vpermw/vpermd/vpermq.  The intrinsics guide is missing `_mm512_permutexvar_epi16` (nvm, it just isn't marked as a "swizzle"))  There are even 2-source variable-control shuffles, so you can have a 512b vector pick bytes/words/dwords/qwords from 2 other 512b vectors!

Comment: So basically writing code that has to shuffle is going to be awesome... in maybe 10 years when we can sometimes give up on vectorizing for CPUs without AVX512.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as you can assume SSSE3 then you can use `pshufb` aka [`_mm_shuffle_epi8`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_shuffle_epi8&expand=4699,4699,4699):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h>  // SSSE3

int main()
{
    __m128i v_in = _mm_setr_epi16(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    __m128i v_perm = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 8, 9, 2, 3, 10, 11, 4, 5, 12, 13, 6, 7, 14, 15);
    __m128i v_out = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v_in, v_perm); // pshufb
    printf("v_in  = %vhd\n", v_in);
    printf("v_out = %vhd\n", v_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -mssse3 green_goblin.c 
$ ./a.out 
v_in  = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
v_out = 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

---

Alternate solution which relies only on SSE2:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>  // SSE2

int main()
{
    __m128i v_in = _mm_setr_epi16(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    __m128i v_out = _mm_shuffle_epi32(v_in, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0)); // pshufd
    v_out = _mm_shufflelo_epi16(v_out, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));      // pshuflw
    v_out = _mm_shufflehi_epi16(v_out, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));      // pshufhw
    printf("v_in  = %vhd\n", v_in);
    printf("v_out = %vhd\n", v_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -msse2 green_goblin_sse2.c 
$ ./a.out 
v_in  = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
v_out = 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

Comment: #!¤52#¤ASDFWERTøøøøåååå! I just was about to paste exactly your answer and you beat me to it again!

Comment: @BharatAhuja, it's easy the short index uses byte index 2*i and 2*i+1.  E.g. short index 3 becomes byte index 6 and 7.

Comment: @Zboson: you'll just have to get up earlier ! ;-)

Comment: @Zboson thanx got it